# Secret track on Underworld's "Beaucoup Fish"

Tags: house, hidden-track

On [Underworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld_(band))'s 1999 album [*Beaucoup Fish*](https://www.discogs.com/Underworld-Beaucoup-Fish/release/3645) I was told there is a secret track. It is heard by playing [*Winjer*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dswCrAXFCrA) (track 5) and one other track, but I do not not know which one. The other track would also be from the same album.

Is this true? Has anyone else heard of, created or have any evidence for this?

Comment: Hi. With what medium does it supposed to happen (CD, Vinyl...)? Do you found at least one online (even non official) statement about this, from what I found, there is no secret track on this album and this weird way of "activating" a secret track does not exist on LP or CD.

Comment: @bebs I agree it is a strange way to hide a track which makes it even more interesting! I can only guess it would be played by playing the to tracks at the same time with 2 decks.